# Complete the pattern

Tags: pattern

I have been creating puzzles to promote our school's [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ElroiAcademy/), but in a week no-one could yet answer this one:

Complete the pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is:

> C

because:

> Let white=0, grey=1, black=2. Adding the first two squares from either rows or columns and subtract 3 if the answer is greater than 2 gives the third square in the row/column.

Answer (score 5):

Answer is:

> C

Because:

> Black + black = gray.
> Gray + gray = black.
> Color + white = color.

Comment: What about Black + Gray?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It looks like Danne used the term "color" to mean either black or grey. That makes sense when also considering how other answers assign the value of $0$ to white, as $x + 0 = x$.

Comment: Don't forget: White $+$ White $=$ White.

Comment: @maxathousand But that when "color" is added to white. I'm asking about Black + Gray.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir oh wow, hahha totally misread that. You’re right

Comment: Ah, forgot about that case yes :) black + gray = white of course ;)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> C.

Due to:

> Assign black, grey, and white the values, and 0 respectively (Black would be 2, grey 1, and white 0). Now the top-left square would look like this: 
> $$\begin{bmatrix}2 &  1  & 0\\1  &  2 & 1 \\0  &   1  &  2 \end{bmatrix}$$ And the middle-left like this:
> $$\begin{bmatrix}0 &  0  & 0\\1  &  1 & 1 \\2  &   2  &  2 \end{bmatrix}$$ Adding them together would result in a square looking like this: 
> $$\begin{bmatrix}2 &  1  & 0\\2  &  3 & 2 \\2  &   3  &  4 \end{bmatrix}$$ Which has values greater than 2, so we use a modulo function (which gives the remainder of a division) to subtract three from all values greater than 2, gives a box with the following values: 
> $$\begin{bmatrix}2 &  1  & 0\\2  &  0 & 2 \\2  &   0  &  1 \end{bmatrix}$$ Which is the bottom-left matrix. Doing this procedure to the right column gives you a matrix with the values of C.

Sorry for all the math jargon in my answer, if it caused any trouble.

Comment: *Hello!* Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**. Congratulations on your very first answer, here, and it is a great one too — it is thorough; well-explained; and easy to understand. However, since you are new, I advise that you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and, since you have not asked a question as of yet, I highly suggest you go [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to look at info about questions. Otherwise, keep puzzling! $$\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$